# Strange error in tableplot (Error in dim(values)...)

Tags: r

Following the example here in RStudio:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tabplot/vignettes/tabplot-vignette.html

I get "Error in dim(values)...". This happens with any data set I try to plot using tableplot. Could it have something to do with my graphics device? I tried writing to a png but get the same error.

```
tableplot(diamonds)
Error in dim(values) <- c(rows, cols, 1) : 
  dims [product 539400] do not match the length of object [10]
```

Comment: Seems like maybe I was using the wrong package. I restarted, cleared my environment and ran: 

install.packages("tabplot")
library(tabplot)

and that fixed the error.

Comment: Not sure where the tableplot() method was coming from if tabplot was not installed.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue.  The problem is that there is a library called "tabplot" and a library called "tableplot"  To make it even more confusing, they both have a tableplot function.  Essentially you want:

```
tabplot::tableplot(diamonds)
```

Too many R packages.

Comment: I am not able to use package 'tabplot' as it seems deprecated in R version>3.6. I tried downloading package 'tableplot' instead but still the error persists. Is there any alternative way to generate plots as shown in the example with diamonds data?

Answer (score 3):

the code you link to (with some `install.packages` added) works for me (R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) and ggplot2_2.0.0)

```
# install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)
require(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
## add some NA's
is.na(diamonds$price) <- diamonds$cut == "Ideal"
is.na(diamonds$cut) <- (runif(nrow(diamonds)) > 0.8)

# install.packages("tabplot", dependencies = TRUE)
require(tabplot)
tableplot(diamonds)
```

[image: sjhsj]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I need to close this question since I can't reproduce it, but I'm not sure how to do this on SO.